# What do these errors mean? ISOC++ forbids assignment of arrays

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, libraries, rhel

I'm trying to compile some code on one of our systems for our DBA...I've edited the makefiles to include the pertinent libraries listed in the documentation, but I keep getting these errors... Can you discern any obvious problems from my command lines in reference to the errors listed?

Thank you!

make -f /u01/app/banner/ban8/TEST3/links/Makefile_tm_linux64_redhat5_ban8.mk

gcc -m64 -D_NOFIXARGPTR -fpic -shared -DTMCILIB_EXPORTS -D_TMUNICODE
        -I/usr/local/ban_icu -I/usr/local/src/icu/source/i18n/ -I/usr/local/src/icu/source/common/ -I/usr/local/src/icu/source/extra/ustdio/ -I/usr/local/src/icu/source/io  -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/src/icu/source/data/ -L/usr/local/src/icu/source/data/out/ -L/usr/local/src/icu/source/tools/toolutil/ -L/usr/lib/im/icuconv/ -L/usr/local/lib/ -L. -licui18n -licudata -licuuc -licu-toolutil -licuio
        msgfmttm.cpp umsgtm.cpp tmcilib.cpp -o /u01/app/banner/ban8/TEST3/general/exe/libtmciuc.so

umsgtm.cpp: In function ‘void fixArgPtr(const UChar*, __va_list_tag (*)[1])’:

umsgtm.cpp:158: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer

umsgtm.cpp:194: error: ISO C++ forbids assignment of arrays

umsgtm.cpp: In function ‘int32_t tmumsg_vformat(void**, UChar*, int32_t, __va_list_tag*, UErrorCode*)’:

umsgtm.cpp:305: error: cannot convert ‘__va_list_tag**’ to ‘__va_list_tag (*)[1]’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘void fixArgPtr(const UChar*, __va_list_tag (*)[1])’

tmcilib.cpp: In function ‘int tmprintf(TMBundle*, const UChar*, ...)’:

tmcilib.cpp:743: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer

tmcilib.cpp: In function ‘int tmfprintf(TMBundle*, UFILE*, const UChar*, ...)’:

tmcilib.cpp:757: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer

tmcilib.cpp: In function ‘int tmsprintf(TMBundle*, UChar*, const UChar*, ...)’:

tmcilib.cpp:808: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer

Comment: looks like the code is initialising arrays incorrectly.

Comment: The command line specifies `-D_NOFIXARGPTR`, and the first function giving the errors is called `fixArgPtr`. Look at the source for that function, maybe it's initializing arrays using a macro which some header should have set up but didn't, because _NOFIXARGPTR told it that it wasn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that url => [here](http://h30097.www3.hp.com/docs/base_doc/DOCUMENTATION/V40F_HTML/AQTLTBTE/DOCU_046.HTM) will help you.